# Java web-services concurrency issues

Tags: java, web-services, concurrency, synchronization

I have a java method calling on a web service and making changes to the database based on the response. My task is to eliminate concurrency errors when several users use this application simultaneously.

I was trying to use various types of database locking all day but nothing worked. I finally tried to use synchronized in the process request method and it all worked.

My whole application is single-threaded. Why does synchronized solve this?

Edit: Added Code.

```
public class ProcessMakePaymentServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private DbBean db = new DbBean();

    protected synchronized void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // defining variables...

        try {

            // initialize parameters for invoking remote method

            db.connect(); 
            startTransaction(); //autocommit=0; START TRANSACTION;
            // process debit
            //this method gets the method using a select...for update. 
            //it then updates it with the new value
            successfulDebit = debitAccount(userId, amt);
            if (successfulDebit) {
                // contact payment gateway by invoking remote pay web service method here.

                // create new instances of remote Service objects
                org.tempuri.Service service = new org.tempuri.Service();
                org.tempuri.ServiceSoap port = service.getServiceSoap();

                // invoke the remote method by calling port.pay().
                // port.pay() may time out if the remote service is down and throw an exception
                successfullyInformedPaymentGateway = port.pay(bankId, bankPwd, payeeId, referenceId, amt);

                if (successfullyInformedPaymentGateway) {
                    // insert payment record
                    recordPaymentMade(userId, amt, referenceId); 
                    //call to the database to record the transaction. Simple update statement.
                    out.println("<br/>-----<br/>");
                    //getTotalPaymentMade does a select to sum all the payment amounts
                    out.println("Total payment made so far to gateway: " + getTotalPaymentMade());
                    commitTransaction();// calls COMMIT
                    db.close(); //connection closed.
                } else {
                    rollbackTransaction();//calls ROLLBACK
                    db.close();
                    successfulDebit = false;
                    out.println("<br/>-----<br/>");
                    out.println("Incorrect bank details.");
                }
            } else {
                rollbackTransaction();//calls ROLLBACK
                db.close();
                out.println("<br/>-----<br/>");
                out.println("Invalid payment amount.");
            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                rollbackTransaction();//calls ROLLBACK
                db.close();
            } catch (Exception ex1) {
            }
        }

  }
```

Comment: So there is no concurrent access to your web-service, only one client?

Comment: What do you mean by "your whole application is single-threaded"?

Comment: @Dave Newton None of my classes have a extends Thread thing.

Comment: @home there is concurrent access to the web-service

Comment: @Nikunj That's not what determines if your server is handling requests in a single-threaded mode.

Comment: @DaveNewton Okay nice. thanks. So any idea why synchronized solves this issue and not row locking on the db?

Comment: @Nikunj: You're sure you implemented row locking the right way - did you test it? There are a number of things that could be wrong in your service, e.g. using a shared `java.sql.Connection` object.

Comment: @Nikunj Depends on how you're doing the row locking and how your service handler works. Impossible to say without knowing what you're doing, what framework you're using, etc.

Comment: @home - yes! thats right i am using one sql connection for the entire class. I have a DbBean and it is created at the start of the class as a global variable. then, within the method, i connect to the db, get a few values, call the webservice and commit the values to the db. then i close the connection. 

I tested my row locking in the sense that every thing works if i remove the webservice and simulate it using a random value generated in the method. But once i start calling the web service, the inconsistencies start to appear.

Comment: Time to post the (relevant) code... Neverthess, one global instance of `java.sql.Connection` is likely to cause the problem. You should obtain a new connection from `javax.sql.DataSource` on each and every call.

Comment: @home - Thanks for the tip on javax.sql.DataSource. Will look into that. Posted the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move `private DbBean db = new DbBean();` into the servlet method, this should solve the problem concurrency problem:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {

  // defining variables...
  DbBean db = new DbBean();

...
}
```

Nevertheless, you should properly clean all database resources in a `finally` block. A fairly simplified example, but I hope you get what I mean:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {

  // defining variables...
  DbBean db = null;
  boolean commit = false;

  try {
    db = new DbBean();
  } catch (SomeException e) {
    commit = false;
  } finally{
    db.release(commit); /* close database connection => java.sql.Connection#close() */
  }

...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Give me sometime to try this out. i will get back to you :)

Answer (score 2):

> My whole application is single-threaded. Why does synchronized solve
>   this?

No it is not single threaded. The web service is called by multiple threads receiving the client requests.

The web service method implementation must take care of **all** synchronization issues same as in a servlet implementation receiving multiple requests, care must be taken to ensure thread safety.

In your case, by adding synchronized you made sure that concurrent processing of web service client request did not result in corruption due to thread issues and you are esentially serializing the client requests (and there of access to the DB).

You have not posted any code to see what you are doing wrong, but since synchronized at the web method level solves your problem, you either did not do the synchronized at the DB level as you say properly or threading issues corrupted common variables at the web service layer accessing the DB.

By `synchronizing` at the web method, the code is thread safe, but the performance will deteriorate since you will serve 1 client at a time.

Depends on what your requirements are

Comment: Thanks for this! it helped with my understanding alot!